# How to convert single-row pandas data frame to series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm somewhat new to pandas. I have a pandas data frame that is 1 row by 23 columns.

I want to convert this into a series. I'm wondering what the most pythonic way to do this is?

I've tried `pd.Series(myResults)` but it complains `ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 23 to array axis with dimension 1`. It's not smart enough to realize it's still a "vector" in math terms.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have a one column dataframe df, you can convert it to a series:

```
df.iloc[:,0]  # pandas Series
```

Since you have a one row dataframe `df`, you can transpose it so you're in the previous case:

```
df.T.iloc[:,0]
```

Answer (score 112):

You can transpose the single-row dataframe (which still results in a dataframe) and then [squeeze](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html?highlight=squeeze#squeezing) the results into a series (the inverse of `to_frame`).

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list(range(5))], columns=["a{}".format(i) for i in range(5)])

>>> df.squeeze(axis=0)
a0    0
a1    1
a2    2
a3    3
a4    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

**Note:** To accommodate the point raised by @IanS (even though it is not in the OP's question), test for the dataframe's size.  I am assuming that `df` is a dataframe, but the edge cases are an empty dataframe, a dataframe of shape (1, 1), and a dataframe with more than one row in which case the use should implement their desired functionality.

```
if df.empty:
    # Empty dataframe, so convert to empty Series.
    result = pd.Series()
elif df.shape == (1, 1)
    # DataFrame with one value, so convert to series with appropriate index.
    result = pd.Series(df.iat[0, 0], index=df.columns)
elif len(df) == 1:
    # Convert to series per OP's question.
    result = df.T.squeeze()
else:
    # Dataframe with multiple rows.  Implement desired behavior.
    pass
```

This can also be simplified along the lines of the answer provided by @themachinist.

```
if len(df) > 1:
    # Dataframe with multiple rows.  Implement desired behavior.
    pass
else:
    result = pd.Series() if df.empty else df.iloc[0, :]
```

Comment: Note that I ran into a small issue using `squeeze`. For a dataframe of shape `(1, 1)` it will return, not a series of length 1, but a numpy scalar. This led to a hard-to-catch bug when using `squeeze` on objects of unknown length (e.g. with `groupby`).

Comment: "Thank you! df.squeeze() worked when df.iloc[:,0] & df.ix[:,0] both produced too many indexes error"

Comment: And why is the inverse of `to_frame` not `to_series` or `pd.Series(df)` ...?

Comment: You don't need `.T`

Comment: @IanS pass the argument `df.squeeze(axis=0)` or `df.squeeze(axis=1)` (depending on the axis you want to conserve) to avoid that

Comment: I think it is wise to always specify the axis to squeeze

Answer (score 82):

> It's not smart enough to realize it's still a "vector" in math terms.

Say rather that it's smart enough to recognize a difference in dimensionality. :-)

I think the simplest thing you can do is select that row positionally using `iloc`, which gives you a Series with the columns as the new index and the values as the values:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([list(range(5))], columns=["a{}".format(i) for i in range(5)])
>>> df
   a0  a1  a2  a3  a4
0   0   1   2   3   4
>>> df.iloc[0]
a0    0
a1    1
a2    2
a3    3
a4    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64
>>> type(_)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Or, another way: `df.T`

Comment: @ako: `df.T` doesn't produce a Series, though, just a transposed DataFrame.

Comment: @DSM. That's true, df.T.iloc[0]

Comment: The only problem with using `df.iloc` is that if you have an empty df, this will raise an `IndexError`. To avoid that, after transposing your df, use the `df.squeeze` method. Ref. to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html

Comment: @DSM Yes, using `df.iloc` is the best way!

Answer (score 39):

You can retrieve the series through slicing your dataframe using one of these two methods:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(1,8))

series1=df.iloc[0,:]
type(series1)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use stack()

```
df= DataFrame([list(range(5))], columns = [“a{}”.format(I) for I in range(5)])
```

After u run df, then run:

```
df.stack()
```

You obtain your dataframe in series

Comment: `stack()` is the only solution robust enough not to return a single element instead of the expected single column...

Answer (score 6):

**Another way -**

Suppose myResult is the dataFrame that contains your data in the form of 1 col and 23 rows

```
# label your columns by passing a list of names
myResult.columns = ['firstCol']

# fetch the column in this way, which will return you a series
myResult = myResult['firstCol']

print(type(myResult))
```

In similar fashion, you can get series from Dataframe with multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,34],"b":[5,6,7,8]})
new_data = pd.melt(data)
new_data.set_index("variable", inplace=True)
```

This gives a dataframe with index as column name of data and all data are present in "values" column

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How does this answer the question? Your code doesn't return a Series like the question asks

Answer (score 1):

Another way is very simple

```
df= df.iloc[3].reset_index(drop=True).squeeze()
```

Squeeze -> is the one that converts to Series.