# How to convert a single column Pandas DataFrame into Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'gene' : ['foo','bar'],'score' : [4., 3.,]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.set_index('gene',inplace=True)
```

Which make:

```
In [56]: df
Out[56]:
      score
gene
foo       4
bar       3
In [58]: type(df)
Out[58]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

What I want to do is to turn it into a Series.
I expect it to to return:

```
gene
foo       4
bar       3
#pandas.core.series.Series
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
In [64]: type(df.iloc[0:,])
Out[64]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [65]: df.iloc[0:,]
Out[65]:
      score
gene
foo       4
bar       3
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try swapping the indices in the brackets:

```
df.iloc[:,0]
```

This should work.

Comment: Note also @Alexander's answer below. This answer will lead to ambiguity if there is more than one column. Squeeze simply fails and that is what you often want.

Answer (score 28):

```
s = df.squeeze()
>>> s
gene
foo    4
bar    3
Name: score, dtype: float64
```

To get it back to a dataframe:

```
>>> s.to_frame()
      score
gene       
foo       4
bar       3
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246771/convert-pandas-data-frame-to-series/40208359#40208359

Comment: Note that if your DataFrame is of a single element, `squeeze()` will return a scalar. In this way `iloc[:,0]` will return a more consistent result.

Answer (score 1):

**Swapping the indices would solve the problem easily:**

```
In [64]: type(df.iloc[0:,])
Out[64]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [65]: df.iloc[[:,0] // Swaped the indices
Out[65]:
        score
gene
foo       4
bar       3
```