# Converting pandas dataframe to pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I need some help with a data types issue.
I'm trying to convert a pandas dataframe, which looks like the following:

```
timestamp    number
2018-01-01     1
2018-02-01     0
2018-03-01     5
2018-04-01     0
2018-05-01     6
```

into a pandas series, which looks exactly like the dataframe, without the column names timestamp and number:

```
 2018-01-01     1
 2018-02-01     0
 2018-03-01     5
 2018-04-01     0
 2018-05-01     6
```

It shouldn't be difficult, but I'm having a little trouble figuring out the way to do it, as I'm a beginner in pandas.

It would be great to get some help with this issue.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: can you show how the output should look like?

Comment: It should look just like the dataframe, but without the column names 'timestamp' and 'number' on it.

Comment: I am confused here. Why dont you want the names if you want a dataframe back? can you post the output in the question?

Comment: I don't want a dataframe. I want a pandas Series, which doesn't have the names of the columns on it. I just edited the question, now you can check how I want the pandas Series to look like :)

Comment: Do you mean `df.set_index('timestamp')['number'].rename_axis(None)` ?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072010/how-to-convert-a-single-column-pandas-dataframe-into-series

Comment: Yes! This worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use:

```
df.set_index('timestamp')['number'].rename_axis(None)
```

---

```
2018-01-01    1
2018-02-01    0
2018-03-01    5
2018-04-01    0
2018-05-01    6
```