# Upload data from csv to series in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, series

I have a data in a column in a csv format and want to append it in series in python that it can be displayed like:

```
series=[12,13,12,22,34,21]
```

How can it be done? Should I do it via read_csv and then somehow transform it to series or it is a another way?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information: is your column of interest the only column in your csv or just one of many? How do you read the csv, self-implemented or using a certain package? Is the series to be entirely build from the csv or are there previous data in the series where to append the csv data?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC and you are talking about pandas - you can use [squeeze](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter:

```
In [86]: import pandas as pd

In [87]: s = pd.read_csv('d:/temp/.data/1.csv', header=None, squeeze=True)

In [88]: s
Out[88]:
0    12
1    13
2    12
3    22
4    34
5    21
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

as a vanilla Python list:

```
In [89]: s.tolist()
Out[89]: [12, 13, 12, 22, 34, 21]
```

from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **squeeze** : boolean, default False
>
> If the parsed data only contains one column then return a Series

Answer (score 0):

Try `pandas.Series(data=None, index=None, dtype=None, name=None, copy=False, fastpath=False)` after reading your data as data frame with `read_csv`. Pandas [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html)

Another possibility is to use `iloc` function, when you deal with  a row, not a column. See here: [Convert pandas data frame to series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246771/convert-pandas-data-frame-to-series)