# Convert dataframe to series for multiple column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

[image: This is also a dataset contain 2 dimension but it is series type][image: Convert dat frame to series]

I tried to convert the data frame to series But it shows the following error. I used pandas.Series(Dataframe) -> to convert Dataframe to series

I want a output in the format of 1st image

Comment: I would suggest you to see the answer by https://stackoverflow.com/a/33247007/3528612 You should think of it as a problem of converting multiple column to a series. Hence as suggested in the answer by @dsm you should extract columns out of the dataframe.

Comment: Series is a one-dimensional object while DataFrame is multi-dimentional object.
What you're trying to do is assigning multiple columns as a Series.

Comment: series = read_csv('shampoo-sales.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser). If I read the file in this format i got series type with 2 dimension.(1st image in the question)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try the following approach to get a Series object from mentioned data(assuming `data` is the DataFrame you're using)

```
series = pd.Series(data['Sales'], index=data.index)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be series = pd.Series(data['Sales'], index=data.Month) if he wants to  index by the Month column? I have similar problem however when I use this approach I get NaN for my Sales like column.