# Getting NaN converting pandas Dataframe to Series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to convert pandas Dataframe to Series based on accepted answer to [Convert dataframe to series for multiple column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52329220/convert-dataframe-to-series-for-multiple-column)

However I am getting NaN in my integer column 'y'.

Here is my code:

```
data = [['2021-10-14 18:12:00.000', '22811316'],['2021-10-14 18:42:00.000', '22700704']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ds', 'y'])
series = pd.Series(df.y, index=df.ds)
```

printing series gives me:

```
ds
2021-10-14 18:12:00.000    NaN
2021-10-14 18:42:00.000    NaN
Name: y, dtype: object
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find the answer in [pandas.Series() Creation using DataFrame Columns returns NaN Data entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818873/pandas-series-creation-using-dataframe-columns-returns-nan-data-entries)

The trick was to use:

```
series = pd.Series(df.y.values, index=df.ds)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just take the series `df.y`, you will obtain a series with **new** indices starting from 0, 1, ...

```
print(df.y)

0    22811316
1    22700704
Name: y, dtype: object
```

These indices do not match with the values of the column `ds` that you want to use as index.
So, when you create the new series with `index=...`, you will probably have all `NaN`.

In order to put just the values of `y` column into the new series, you have to take only its values using [`to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html)

```
series = pd.Series(df.y.to_numpy(), index=df.ds)
print(series)

ds
2021-10-14 18:12:00.000    22811316
2021-10-14 18:42:00.000    22700704
dtype: object
```