# Pandas : What is the fastest way to get a list of single panda series from a large dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How the questions explain, i search for a very fast split method to get a list of all panda series from a panda dataframe to multiprocessing them. hsplit from numpy split it to single dataframes. Is there a method im not aware of?

Comment: Yeah, iterate through `df.columns`. How fast to do you want it to be? Columns are superficial, they're basically just keys holding Series objects.

Comment: you can use df.iloc[index] it will return row

Comment: Actually, this really doesn't make sense. If you're now turning to multiprocessing, the segmentation of data by column is likely <1% of the overall processing time for whatever you're doing

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to iterate through all the columns `df.iloc[index]` or `df.loc[index]` is probably the best method. However, I don't see how this would be that important. Pandas is already exceptionally efficient for operations and its hard to beat the core dataframe indexer speed.

Comment: Why do any of that when you can just get the column by name?

Comment: It all depend on the @Varlor use case whether he require records column wise or row wise Check the similar case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246771/convert-pandas-data-frame-to-series