# Convert pandas data frame (with multiple columns) to series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to convert my dataframe which looks like:

```
             ds          y
0    1999-01-04   0.000000
1    1999-01-05   1.330603
2    1999-01-06   4.556447
3    1999-01-07   6.823689
4    1999-01-08   8.949833
...         ...        ...
5377 2020-05-18  34.497940
```

To a series that looks like

```
1999-01-04   0.000000
1999-01-05   1.330603
1999-01-06   4.556447
1999-01-07   6.823689
1999-01-08   8.949833
...         ...       
2020-05-18  34.497940
```

I have looked at:
[Convert pandas data frame to series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246771/convert-pandas-data-frame-to-series)
(and many others) and I still cannot accomplish the task.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do

```
s=df.set_index('ds').y
```