# Why Does Pandas Convert One Row (or Column) of a DataFrame to a Series?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

**Context**: I was passing what I thought was a DataFrame, `df.iloc[n]`, into a function. Thanks to the [dialogue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246771/convert-pandas-data-frame-to-series) I figured out this was causing errors because Pandas automatically converts a single row or column from a Dataframe into a series, and is easily solved by using `df.iloc[[n]]` instead of `df.iloc[n]`.

**Question**: My question is *why* does Pandas do this? Is there some performance benefit in using Series instead of DataFrames? What is the reasoning behind this automatic conversion to a Series?

Comment: It's like asking why indexing 2d array converts it to a 1d array. It does not convert it to a Series, the row of the dataframe is logically a Series, not a dataframe. Technically speaking it's the difference between shapes of `(c,)` of `df.iloc[n]` and `(1, c)` of `df.iloc[[n]]` where `c` is a number of columns.

Comment: I don't think what you're saying is quite right: `type(df.iloc[n])` is a Series, whereas `type(df.iloc[[n]])` is a DataFrame. This isn't just dimensionality: I can call `df.iloc[[n]].columns`, whereas `df.iloc[n].columns` throws an Error. There's real functionality change here, not just dimensionality change. My question is why does Pandas go through the effort to make this functionality change? There must be a reason for it. What is that reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Pandas documentation [Why more than one data structure?](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/overview.html#data-structures)

*The best way to think about the pandas data structures is as flexible containers for lower dimensional data. For example, DataFrame is a container for Series, and Series is a container for scalars. We would like to be able to insert and remove objects from these containers in a dictionary-like fashion.*

So, no conversion happening here, rather objects with different properties/methods being retrieved.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you: "...objects with different properties/methods being retrieved" is exactly the insight I needed.